# Import CSV containing complex JSON to Postgres

Tags: python, json, postgresql, csv

I have a CSV file, of which one of the columns, `json_dic`, contains complex JSON, with many nested fields within lists within dictionaries etc.

What's the best way of uploading this file to a Postgres database so I can access/search for particular fields and retrieve that data from an SQL query?

For example, I have millions of rows of the following:

[image]

The JSON column `json_doc` looks like this, but it isn't consistent for other rows i.e. there are other nested dictionaries in different places etc:

```
{"id": "0436d9b9305d", "base": {"ateco": [{"code": "46.11.03", "rootCode": "G", "description": "Agenti e rappresentanti di animali vivi"}], "founded": "1972-07-10", "legalName": "COBEM - S.R.L.", "legalForms": [{"name": "Società Di Capitale", "level": 1}, {"name": "Società A Responsabilità Limitata", "level": 2}]}, "name": "COBEM - S.R.L.", "people": {"items": [{"name": "45808b0b5b5affa871c8e91169bb10c6930fac56", "givenName": "64e4393f477394f11f6477ca76395ed469548865", "familyName": "68ee44f14dc54d664dffe63195d42a14988b69bb"}]}, "country": "it", "locations": {}}
```

How can I upload this, either in it's current CSV form or in a JSON format to PostgreSQL? I've been searching for days for the answer but am getting nowhere. I've tried to use COPY, use pandas, `json_normalize`, etc. I want to be able to do a join to match i.e. ID numbers with a different table, and then pull through bits of information from this complex file. Is this even possible?

One of my attempts:

```
import csv
import json 

csvfile = open('sample.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('data.json', 'w')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
i = 0
for row in reader:
    if i < 3:
        json.dump(row, jsonfile)
        i+=1
    else:
        break
```

And then in my psql terminal :

```
SN_ITA_test=# \COPY public."ITA_test" FROM 'data.json';
```

Yields:

```
  ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY ITA_test, line 1: "{"id": "4002736", "json_doc": "{\"id\": \"0436d9b9305d\", \"base\": {\"ateco\": [{\"code\": \"46.11...."
```

Comment: What are your requirements? You can read the file as a whole and throw it into a single BLOB, but that is probably not what you want. BTW: One thing I'd start with is to fix the metaformat to not be a mixture of JSON in CSV but only one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt - I've isolated just the json_doc column into a separate csv. I did this by going into Mac numbers and deleted the irrelevant columns and exporting to csv.

I want to be able to do a join with another file based on the ID, and pull through various fields from this file such as legal name, address, etc. I'm a bit worried though because there isn't much consistency in the format of the json_doc column

Answer (score 0):

If your data are in CSV format, you'll have to tell `COPY`:

```
\copy public."ITA_test" FROM 'data.json' (FORMAT 'csv')
```

The default format is `text`, where the fields are separated by tab characters.

If, on the other hand, one line of the file is just one big JSON, you'd load it similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE jsons (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   j jsonb NOT NULL
);

\copy jsons (j) FROM 'data.json'
```

Comment: Thanks Laurenz - I get 

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "id" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"json_doc": "{"id...
COPY jsons, line 1, column j: "{"json_doc": "{"id": "0436d9b9305d", "base": {"ateco": [{"code": "46.11.03", "rootCode": "G", "descr..."

Comment: To understand that error, I'd have to have an exact copy if that file. There must be some weirdness in it, because the JSON you show above is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a huge CSV file, and since your requirements seem to be non-trivial, I would suggest using the csv2json program at https://github.com/fadado/CSV in conjunction with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq). You would use jq to process each row produced by csv2json separately.

If you don’t want to process each CSV record separately (i.e., without converting the entire CSV file), you might wish to consider an only-jq solution, using a CSV parser witten in jq, e.g. https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/bbbbdf7489c8c515680beb1c75fa59f2